# If external url contains this url then

Tags: laravel, knockout.js, laravel-blade

I have this controller which is storing the host and url of a video in youtube, vimeo, vevo etc

```
public function attach()
{
    $input = Input::except('_token');

    if ( ! Input::get('host') || ! Input::get('url')) {
        return Response::json(trans('video::main.fillAllRequiredFields'), 400);
    }
}
```

And in the blade i have this

```
@foreach ($title->link as $k => $video)
    <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">{{ $video->host }}</a></p>
@endforeach
```

So as for now the member has to insert both the url and the label of the host..

I want to use a function either in Laravel or knockout.js so when an url is inserted to extract the host and show the host label automatically without been stored in DB. Something like this

```
@foreach ($title->link as $k => $video)
    @if {{$video->url}} contain "youtube.com" 
    <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">YouTube</a>

    @elseif {{$video->url}} contain "vimeo.com"
    <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">Vimeo</a>

    @elseif {{$video->url}} contain "vevo.com"
    <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">Vimeo</a>

    @else <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">Unknown</a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe you could use PHP's `parse_url` and grab the host from there

Comment: You have a Link Model, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP function strpos() allows you to check if the url string has specific host inside it or not. For example like this

```
@foreach ($title->link as $k => $video)
    @if(strpos($video->url, "youtube.com")!==false) 
    <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">YouTube</a>

    @if(strpos($video->url, "vimeo.com")!==false) 
    <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">Vimeo</a>

    @if(strpos($video->url, "vevo.com")!==false) 
    <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">Vevo</a>

    @else <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ $video->url }}">Unknown</a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```